# NativeBase Content not rendered in Jest with react-native-testing-library

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, native-base, react-testing-library

I have some **react-native/expo** with **native-base** code that runs normally on the phone or emulator.
I tried creating a test for it using **jest** and **react-native-testing-library**. When doing so, whatever is inside the  from **native-base** is not rendered and cannot be found in the test.

**Has anyone been through this and would know a solution so the children of Content are rendered during testing?**

An example code is below to illustrate what I am saying.
Thank you very much for the help.

```py
import { render } from 'react-native-testing-library';
import {
  Content, Container, Text
} from 'native-base';


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Text testID="textId">Hello</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

describe('Testing Content', () => {
  const { queryByTestId } = render(<App />)
  it('renders text inside content', () => {
    expect(queryByTestId('textId')).not.toBeNull()
  });

})
```

The versions of the packages are:

```py
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"react": "16.5.0",
"native-base": "^2.12.1",
"jest-expo": "^32.0.0",
"react-native-testing-library": "^1.7.0"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked the question in the react-native-testing-library in github (https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/118).

The issue is with **react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view**

To solve it, we can mock it the following way

```py
jest.mock('react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view', () => {
    const KeyboardAwareScrollView = ({ children }) => children;
    return { KeyboardAwareScrollView };
});
```

I also put an example here for whoever might be looking:
https://github.com/pedrohbtp/rntl-content-bug

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. I followed your instructions from you github repo but its says `Cannot find module 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view' from 'src/screens/Login.test.tsx'`

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2022**

I found the solution in their docs:

To fix the above issue, you can simply pass initialWindowMetrics to NativeBaseProvider in your tests.

```
const inset = {
  frame: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 },
  insets: { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 },
};

<NativeBaseProvider initialWindowMetrics={inset}>
  {children}
</NativeBaseProvider>;
```