# Error when testing NativeBase component with jest

Tags: react-native, ts-jest, native-base, react-native-testing-library

I'm receiving the following errors when trying to perform component tests using Jest, Testing Library React Native, and Native Base.

1. If I pass the initialWindowMetrics property as stated in the documentation, I receive the following error:
   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.
   Check the render method of ForwardRef
2. If I don't provide the above property, I get an error saying that the testID could not be found.

   Code Button:

   ```
   import { Button, IButtonProps, Icon, Text } from 'native-base'

   import { ExportIcons } from '@utils/exportIcons'
   import { ColorIcons } from '@utils/exportColorsIcons'

   import { IconType } from 'src/types/Icon.types'

   export interface SimpleButtonProps extends IButtonProps {
     width: number | string
     backgroundColor?: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'red' | 'gray.900'

     text: string
     colorTextButton?: 'white' | 'gray.300'
     fontFamily: 'heading' | 'body'
     fontSize: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl'

     hasIcon?: boolean
     iconProps?: IconType
   }

   export function SimpleButton({
     width,
     isDisabled,
     backgroundColor,

     text,
     fontSize,
     fontFamily,
     colorTextButton,

     hasIcon = false,
     iconProps,

     ...rest
   }: SimpleButtonProps) {
     return (
       <Button
         testID="simpleButtonId"
         rounded="full"
         _pressed={{
           opacity: 80
         }}
         _disabled={{ opacity: 60 }}
         w={width}
         bg={backgroundColor}
         isDisabled={isDisabled}
         leftIcon={
           hasIcon && iconProps?.name !== undefined && iconProps.color !== undefined ? (
             <Icon as={ExportIcons[iconProps.name]} fill={ColorIcons[iconProps.color]} />
           ) : undefined
         }
         {...rest}
       >
         <Text testID="text-simple-button" color={colorTextButton} fontSize={fontSize} fontFamily={fontFamily}>
           {text}
         </Text>
       </Button>
     )
   }
   ```

   Code Test Button:

   ```
   import { NativeBaseProvider } from 'native-base'
   import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native'

   import { SimpleButton } from '@components/SimpleButton'

   import { THEME } from '../../theme'

   describe('SimpleButton', () => {
     test('Checks if rendering occurs', () => {
       const { debug, getByTestId } = render(
         <NativeBaseProvider theme={THEME}>
           <SimpleButton
             width={80}
             colorTextButton="white"
             backgroundColor="secondary"
             text="Titulo Botão"
             fontFamily="heading"
             fontSize="sm"
             onPress={() => {
               console.log('teste')
             }}
           />
         </NativeBaseProvider>
       )
       debug()
       const element = getByTestId('text-simple-button')

       console.log(element)
     })
   })
   ```

   Attached is the error

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohcvc.png)

I have already tried some alternatives such as:

[Issue Github](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1230);
[Question in overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333004/nativebase-content-not-rendered-in-jest-with-react-native-testing-library);
[Docs Native Base](https://docs.nativebase.io/testing);

But all of them have been unsuccessful.